# Does the Shackle Spell allow for Held Charge?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, touch-attacks

[Shackle](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/shackle/)

Does the Shackle Spell allow for held charges? The way the spell is worded, my GM believes that the way the spell is worded, I'd only be able to use the touch attack option during the turn it's cast. We're not sure, so for the current session, we're proceeding under the "let's not try it until we're sure" approach.

Does the held charge rule apply here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The caster can't hold the charge of the spell [*shackle*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/shackle/)

While the spell [*shackle*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/shackle/) does have the entry *Range: Touch*—making it so the spell *should* follow the general rules as described in [Magic](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/) on [Range](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Range) on Touch and in [Combat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/) on [Cast a Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Cast-a-Spell) on Touch Spells in Combat—, the spell *shackle* has specific rules for what occurs when upon the spell's completion as per the spell's description.

That is, instead of the normal rules for a spell with an entry of *Range: Touch*, the caster of *shackle* can ***either*** have "the restraints appear in [the caster's] hands" ***or*** "as part of the spell’s casting" the caster "can attempt a melee touch attack against a creature; if [the caster] succeed[s] and the creature then fails a Reflex saving throw, locked fetters appear clasped on the creature or locked manacles clasp you and the creature together."

This second choice *replaces* the caster's typical ability to hold the *shackle* spell's charge, despite its range of touch. (Further, if it matters, this specificity may also prevent the spell effect from being delivered by an unarmed strike instead of a melee touch attack; ask the GM.)

Comment: I've been thinking about your answer for a while now, but I'm still not 100% sure on what the reasoning is. Doesn't the caster have to determine at the time the spell is cast which version of Shackle is being cast? Wouldn't this then mean that the spell otherwise counts as a standard touch attack? You're saying it **replaces** it, but from the way it reads, the intention seems that the spell for all intents and purposes becomes a touch attack which clasps the target to you on a failed save. Why is it that that wording is a "replacement" and why is it incompatible with a held charge?

Comment: @Axoren That's a fair followup. My reading is that it's a replacement *because* it has the entry *Range: Touch* then specifically describes what this spell's range of touch *means.* If holding the charge were possible, there'd be no need to detail that the caster specifically needed to make a touch attack as part of the spell's casting. The specificity *removes* the option of holding a charge by making an exception to the normal rules. The caster can't hold the charge for the same reason the caster can't punch a subject into irons: the spell says so.

Comment: @Axoren The *alternative* gives the spell three modes: 1) make a chain in hand, 2) use it as a normal touch spell, or 3) use it as a touch spell as described by the spell itself. Since #2 is in all ways better and more versatile and even includes #3, there'd never be any reason to use #3, and the spell description could be chopped in half.

Answer (score -1):

**Nothing indicates you can't hold a charge of Shackle**

If you do not perform the first portion:

> You summon a set of Small or Medium masterwork restraints into being.

Then you have a Touch spell, which holds its charge as normal:

> However, as part of the spell’s casting, you can attempt a melee touch attack against a creature; if you succeed and the creature then fails a Reflex saving throw, locked fetters appear clasped on the creature or locked manacles clasp you and the creature together. You can instead choose to have manacles restrain the target’s limbs in front of or behind it.

It does not indicate that the shackles appear whether you hit or not, nor that the charge is lost on a failed touch. For these reasons, when you *choose* to perform the touch attack version, you have a held charge until you touch something, as normal.